# beautifulsoup scraping - expandable header text missing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was trying to extract data from a Y!Finance website using BeautifulSoup and store everything in a list. In the list, the headers of the expandable lines (Total Revenue, Operating Expense) are missing but the figures are still there. Is there a way to include the headers in the output?

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as ur

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL'

read_data = ur.urlopen(url).read() 
soup= BeautifulSoup(read_data,'lxml')

ls= [] # Create empty list
for l in soup.find_all('div'): 
  ls.append(l.string) 


new_ls = list(filter(None,ls))
```

Current output:

```
 'Expand All',
 'ttm',
 '9/30/2019',
 '9/30/2018',
 '9/30/2017',
 '9/30/2016',
 '273,857,000',
 '260,174,000',
 '265,595,000',
 '229,234,000',
 '215,639,000',
```

Expected output:

```
 'Expand All',
 'ttm',
 '9/30/2019',
 '9/30/2018',
 '9/30/2017',
 '9/30/2016',
 'Total Revenue',
 '273,857,000',
 '260,174,000',
 '265,595,000',
 '229,234,000',
 '215,639,000',
```

Update: if I extract from "span", figures that are 0 were missing from the output which creates another problem when I construct the data frame later on

```
for l in soup.select('div.D\(tbr\)'): 
    for n in l.select('span'):
        print(n.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will get you all the data, and then you can filter out what you don't need:

```
for row in soup.select('div[data-test="fin-row"]'):     
    for r in row:
        for l in r:
            print(l.text)
    print('-------\n')
```

Output:

```
Total Revenue
273,857,000
260,174,000
265,595,000
-
215,639,000
-------

Cost of Revenue
169,277,000
161,782,000
163,756,000
-
131,376,000
-------

Gross Profit
```

etc.

If you also want to get the headers programmatically, try:

```
head_ind = [55,58,60,62,64,66]
for i in head_ind:
    heads = f'span[data-reactid="{i}"]:not([class])'
    for head in soup.select(heads):
        print(head.text)
```

Output:

```
Breakdown
ttm
9/30/2019
9/30/2018
9/30/2017
9/30/2016
```

Comment: Hi Jack, I actually tried that but ran into another problem. If you look at Basic EPS for instance, the first slot should be "-" or blank. When I get only the "span", those elements went missing so I can not construct a dataframe later on.

Also, is there a non-DIY way of doing this?

Comment: @anhtle I'm not sure why `:not` isn't accepted in your case... Let me look for an alternative.

Comment: I have adjusted your code and it's working now. 

```
head_ind = [55,58,60,62,64,66]

for i in head_ind:

    heads = f'span[data-reactid="{i}"]'
    for head in soup_is.select(heads):
        if not (head.has_attr('class') or head.has_attr('style')):
            ls.append(head.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is kind of off topic, but it looks like you just want the data from Yahoo finance right? If so, they have a python package already available that would probably be easier to work with then web scraping.

https://pypi.org/project/yahoo-finance/

You can enter a share

```
apple = Share('AAPL')
```

And also get a bunch of data by just using the following command

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(yahoo.get_historical('2019-08-10', '2020-01-10'))
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, I am actually more interested in the financial statements rather than the closing prices. Also, I believe that the backing API for yahoo-finance was taken offline so the library is not working for me. I would use this lib instead: https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/